# How can I set up a proxy server in CAM to pull CAM templates from the internet?

Tags: proxy, cloud-automation-manager

I would like to set up a proxy server in CAM to pull templates from the internet. How can I set up and configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the current version of IBM Cloud Automation Manager (2.1.0.3) you cannot pull templates through a proxy. The templates will need to be downloaded from a private / internal Git, or the templates can be loaded 'from scratch' directly in CAM, or CAM will need to be in-front of the proxy.

The following page describes what to do on offline cases: 

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS2L37_2.1.0.2/content/cam_enterprise_starterlibrary_content_deploying.html